# Understanding parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and am trying to call a function which I got from:
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functional_differentiation

```
  derive :: (Fractional a) => a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
  derive h f x = (f (x+h) - f x) / h
```

I am having trouble understanding the parameters of the method and what  h f x correspond to.

From what I understand:

h is a fractional

f is a function which takes in a fractional and returns a fractional

x ?? where does that come from?

however when I type in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let derive h f x = (f (x+h) - f x) / h
Prelude> :t derive
derive :: Fractional a => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
Prelude>
```

I get a different type out of it.

What is going on? Is this some kind of currying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed currying. `(Fractional a) => a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)` and `Fractional a => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a` are the same type because `->` is right associative.

take `add x y = x + y`. Its type is `Int -> Int -> Int` ~ `Int -> (Int -> Int)`. So `add 5` is a function which takes an Int and adds 5 to it.

The reason that one might write the first form may be to put the emphasis on the usage of the curried form of a function.

Answer (score 1):

Because `->` is right associative, the type of `derive` could be written as

```
derive :: (Fractional a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

In other words,

```
derive :: (Fractional a) => a -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
```

equals

```
derive :: (Fractional a) => a -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
```

I think it makes what `x` means quite clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the differentiation can be approximated as:

```
df(x)/dx = (f(x+h) - f(x)) / h , in the limit of h -> 0 at point x
```

where `h` is a small number. In Haskell, `f(x)` is written as `f x`. It takes and `x` and returns a number, just like `f(x)` takes a number and returns another. Your function for derivative is a direct translation. Here, `f` is the function you want to derive at point `x`, with the *small number* `h`.

So for the `deriv`ative, you provide the small number `h`, the function `f` and the point at which you want to calculate the derivative `x`. In Haskell,

```
derive h f x = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. `h` is of type `a`, which could be anything, but it needs an `instance Fractional`. `Fractional` by itself is not a type, but a type class, i.e., interface the type must support.

`f` is a function that takes something of type `a` and returns something of the same type `a`. It should be the same `a` as before. Not some other instance of `Fractional`; the same one.